# How does GCC store member functions in memory?

Tags: c++, performance, gcc, optimization, compiler-optimization

I am trying to minimise the size my class occupies in memory (both data and instructions). I know how to minimise data size, but I am not too familiar with how GCC places member functions.

Are they stored in memory, the same order they are declared in the class?

Comment: Does `-Os` not work well enough?

Comment: Member functions are just functions. They do not add directly to the size of any instantiated objects. Though they do take up space like other functions. But makeing the smaller is usually not a goal (apart from esoterically small devices).

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo  Does the compiler know my access pattern? Does it know which data members/functions are more likely to be called? Can it analyse my critical path?

Comment: @user997112 I think GCC can if you give it profiling data. But how would any of that affect code size if you're trying to get the smallest possible binary?

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo I want to allocate the functions with temporal locality, contiguously.

Comment: If you're using GCC, the `hot` and `cold` [function attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes) may help. But reordering the functions doesn't affect the binary size.

Comment: Thanks. Because there's no padding (unlike for data)?

Comment: You only get *one* function in memory no matter how many *objects* you instantiate. Padding is not relevant to functions.

Comment: Actually function may be padded, e.g. their starting instruction is often 8 or 16 bytes aligned (for cache performance), but that does not matter much.

Comment: You should have shown some actual code in your question.

Comment: Try setting your compiler optimizations for high code space savings.

Comment: Do you have specific size (and perhaps performance) targets, or is this an aesthetic exercise or callisthenics?

Comment: Just a tip: don't bother asking such low level optimization questions and tagging them C++ unless you like an avalanche of "it's not defined in the standard" or "why do you care type" comments and answers (and associated downvotes).  Just use the other tags which usually have few language lawyer types monitoring them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the purpose of in-memory data representation, a C++ `class` can have either plain or static member functions, or `virtual` member functions (including some `virtual`destructor, if any).

Plain or static member functions do not take any space in data memory, but of course their compiled code take some resource, e.g. as binary code in the text or [code segment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_segment) of your executable or your process. Of course, they can also require `static` data (or thread-local data), or local data (e.g. local variables) on the [call stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack).

<sup>My answer is Linux oriented. I don't know Windows, and don't know how GCC work on it.</sup>

Virtual member functions are very often implemented thru [virtual method table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table) (or *vtable*); a `class` having some virtual member functions usually have instances with a single (assuming single-[inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_%28object-oriented_programming%29)) vtable-pointer pointing to that vtable (which is practically some data packed in the text segment).

<sup>Notice that vtables are not mandatory and are not required by C++11 standard. But I don't know any C++ implementation not using them.</sup>

When you are using [multiple-inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance) things become more complex, objects might have *several* vtable pointers.

So if you have a `class` (either a root class, or using *single-inheritance*), the consumption for virtual member functions is one vtable pointer per instance (plus the small space needed by the *single* vtable itself). It won't change (for each instance) if you have only one virtual member function (or destructor) or a thousand of them (what would change is the vtable itself). Each class has its own *single* vtable (unless it has no virtual member function), and each instance has generally one (for single-inheritance case) vtable pointer.

The GCC compiler is free to organize the vtable as it wishes (and its order and layout is an implementation detail you should not care about); see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28849724/841108). In practice (for single-inheritance) for most recent GCC versions, the vtable pointer is the first word of the object, and the vtable contain function pointers in the order of virtual method declaration, but you should not depend on such details.

The GCC compiler is free to organize the functions in the code segment as it wishes, and it would actually reorder them (e.g. for optimizations). Last time I looked, it ordered them in reverse order. But you certainly should not depend on that order! BTW GCC can inline functions (even when not marked `inline`) and clone functions when optimizing. You could also compile *and link* with [link-time optimizations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interprocedural_optimization) (e.g. `make CXX='g++ -flto -Os'`), and you could ask for [profile-guided optimizations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profile-guided_optimization) (for [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html): `-fprofile-generate`, `-fprofile-use`, `-fauto-profile` etc...)

**You should not depend on how the compiler** (and linker)  **is organizing function code or *vtables***. *Leave the optimizations to the compiler* (and such optimizations depend upon your target machine, your compiler flags, and the compiler version). You might also use [function attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) to give hints to the GCC (or Clang/LLVM) compiler (e.g. `__attribute__((cold))`, `__attribute__((noinline))` etc etc....)

If you really need to know how functions are placed (which IMHO is very wrong), study the generated assembly code (e.g. using `g++ -O -fverbose-asm -S`) and be aware that it could vary with compiler versions!

If you need on Linux and Posix systems at runtime to find out the address of a function from its name, consider using [dlsym](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlsym.html) (for Linux, see [dlsym(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html), which also documents `dladdr`). Be aware of [name mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling), which you can disable by declaring such functions as `extern "C"` (see [C++ dlopen minihowto](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/C++-dlopen/)).

BTW, you might compile and link with `-rdynamic` (which is very useful for `dlopen` etc...). If you really need to know the address of functions, use [nm(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nm.1.html) as `nm -C` *your-executable*.

You might also read the [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) specification and [calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) for your target platform (and compiler), e.g. [Linux x86-64 ABI spec](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf).

Comment: Thanks. So my question is, in the binary are the non-virtual functions located in the order they are declared? So the ordering could be non-static_func1, non-static-func2, static-func1, static-func2 etc?

Comment: @user997112: why are you worrying about the order in which they're stored in memory?

Comment: You should not know such implementation details, leave them to the compiler.

Comment: @user997112 - as others implied, you shouldn't need to care about that. But just in case you need them in a particular order, you can just create an array of pointers to the functions in whatever order you want and use that. Keep in mind non static member functions also need an object pointer to be called.

Comment: The ordering of the functions is up to the Linker and the Loader, and the optimization settings of the Linker.  Some linkers alphabetize the functions.  Some may order functions for best use of memory.  Some functions may be *inlined* and not as separate functions.  You may be able to give instructions to the linker as to where to put the functions.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say we have a type `T` with 4 instance methods.

```
class T {
    public:
        void member_function_1() { ... }
        void member_function_2() { ... }
        void member_function_3() { ... }
        void member_function_4() { ... }
};
```

The amount of memory that those methods take up is the same if we instantiate 1 copy of `T`, or if we instantiate 1 million copies of `T`.

Comment: @user997112: Everything in my answer is the still true irrespective of the amount of code in the implementation.

Comment: You're saying functions containing many instructions occupy the same amount of memory as a function which only increments.....?

Comment: @user997112: No. I'm saying that the amount of memory that the methods use is not correlated with the number of instances of the object that you have created over the course of your program.

Comment: But thats not what I was asking? I wanted to know how GCC orders  functions (in the binary).

Comment: @user997112 You kinda are... _"I am trying to minimise the size my class occupies in memory"_. Function size and locality are two unrelated concepts.

Comment: I meant the memory footprint the class member functions consume.

Comment: Why assume @user997112 does not realise that methods will only be instantiated once?

Comment: It's clear to me after reading the other answer and comments that the OP understands that functions don't have a per-instance cost. He just wants to pack all his functions in a certain way, which isn't entirely unreasonable if you have really exhausted more usual avenues of optimization.